# Recycler View - Null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to add a recycler view within one of the 3 tabs I have created. I want the card viewable in one of the tabs.

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
02-04 01:27:59.447 31760-31760/app.com.example.android.prototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.com.example.android.prototype, PID: 31760
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.com.example.android.prototype/app.com.example.android.prototype.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
         at app.com.example.android.prototype.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="Primary\nFragment"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="androidbelieve.com"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

//private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
   // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    /**
     *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
     */

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

    /**
     * Lets inflate the very first fragment
     * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
     */

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
    /**
     * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
     */

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SentFragment()).commit();

            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
            }

            return false;
        }

    });

    /**
     * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
     */

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure the layout you linked is truly named "activity_main.xml". You are inflating that layout and should be able to access the RecyclerView via id...

Comment: @Lucas Thanks, yup it is! But still no luck :(

Comment: Can you tell us which line in your code is throwing the NPE?  That would help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `findViewById` on the recycler view returns null.
You are trying to add the recyclerview within one of the tabs but referencing the recyclerview from the activity, which throws the `NullPointerException`. Make sure you add the recycler view to the activity layout if you are referencing it from the activity code.

If you want to use the recycler view in one of the tabs, you should instead be calling `findViewById` in the respective tab fragment and not the activity.

Comment: I figured it out - but thank you for pointing me to the right direction!